# How to get .IMG image pixels in 0 to 255 range

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I am working with JSRT images on MATLAB. I read the image with >IMG extension using the following code:

```
fid = fopen('G:\JSRTImages\JSRT001.IMG','r','b');
oneSlice = fread(fid, [2048 2048], '*uint16','b');
img = mat2gray(oneSlice, [0,4096]);
imshow(img);
```

The image is displayed. But when I click on any of the pixels, insted of seeing the gray level in the range of 0 to 255 I am shown 'Index' and RGB. RGB is in 0 to 1 range.

I want the image to be in 0 to 255 range for my program. Please help me in doing it.

Comment: Just multiply by 255...

Comment: i tried that before! but i am thinking there must be some other way of doing it.....

Comment: Why? What's wrong with such a simple solution?

Comment: Dont know! but its simple and easy... right!

Comment: as @Dan said, just multiply it? Why do you want to make things complicated.

Comment: You really should just multiply by 255, but the duplicate link I've marked will give you some insight on how to achieve this since you don't believe us.

Comment: @rayyeng: i believe you..... i have read so many replies given by u people.. its very wonderful.

Comment: i multiplied it by 255 and used uint8 conversion... the image is displayed properly.. thank u!